# Docker permission denied for open /etc/docker/daemon.json: permission denied

Tags: docker

I am trying to setup remote host configuration for docker. After setting up certificates i ran dockerd command which is giving error:

```
dockerd --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem   -H=0.0.0.0:2376

>>> unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: open /etc/docker/daemon.json: permission denied
```

I am running from non root user and I've already added my user as part of Docker group. Docker version i am using is:

```
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

I have tried below but still getting same error:

```
1. the /etc/docker/daemon.json file is having {}

2. I also removed the /etc/docker/daemon.json

3. I also changed ownership but same issue.
```

Permissions of daemon.json were: -rw-r--r--

Answer (score 2):

The `dockerd` daemon must be run as root. It is creating networking namespaces, mounting filesystems, and other tasks that cannot be done with a user account. You'll need to run these commands with something like `sudo`.

The docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) is configured to allow the docker client to access the api by users in the docker group. This is the client, not the daemon, so you can't get away with running the daemon as a user.

Comment: Thanks. used `sudo` but i got **Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid**

Comment: @KrishnaSharma this might mean exactly what it says: dockerd is already running - use `ps -ejH` to view the processes list.